# How to query this output in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this data:

```
NAME               AMOUNT              TYPE
-------------------------------------------
Apple               100                Good
Orange              200                Good
Apple               300                Good 
Orange              100               Damage
```

I need an output like this, with `Total Amount = SUM(Damage) - SUM(Good)`:

```
NAME          TOTAL AMOUNT 
--------------------------
Apple             400
Orange            100
```

Comment: select Name, sum(Amount) AS TotalAmount Where Type='Good' group By Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Name   | Amount  |   Type
Apple  |  100    |   Good
Orange |  200    |   Good
Apple  |  300    |   Good
Orange |  100    |   Damage

SELECT t.Name as Name, SUM(t.Good) as Good, SUM(t.Damage) as Damage, SUM(t.Good) - SUM(t.Damage) as Total 
from (
    SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) as 'Good', 0 as 'Damage' 
    FROM `tb_name` 
    where Type = 'Good' group by Name 
 UNION 
    SELECT name, '0' as 'Good', SUM(Amount) as 'Damage' 
    FROM `tb_name` 
    where Type = 'Damage' group by Name) t 
    group by t.Name`;
```

> OUTPUT

```
Name   | Good    |   Damage   |  Total
Apple  |  400    |   0        |  400
Orange |  200    |   100      |  100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FruitName, 
    (select ISNULL(sum(amount),0) 
        from Fruit d 
        where d.FruitName=m.FruitName and d.Type='Good')
     - (select ISNULL(sum(amount),0) 
        from Fruit d where d.FruitName=m.FruitName and d.Type='Damage') 
     as 'Total Amount' 
from Fruit m 
group by FruitName
```